# How to display a DataFrame without Jupyter Notebook crashing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Everytime I try to display a complete DataFrame in my jupyter notebook, the note book crashes. The file wont start up so I had to make a new jupyter notebook file. When i do display(df) it only shows a couple of the rows, when I need to show 57623 rows. I need to show results for all of these rows and put them into an html file.

I tried setting the max rows and max columns, but the entire dataframe would not print out without the notebook crashing

''' python
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 24)
    "pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 57623)
'''

The expected results were for the entire DataFrame to print out, but instead the notebook would have an hourglass next to it and nothing would load.

Comment: Do you need to *show* the results to export them to html?

Comment: you try `df.to_html('nameFile.html')` to save as html?

Comment: My problem is that the entire dataframe doesnt display, when i print out the dataframe only some of the rows show when i need 57623 of them to show.

Comment: This is not as good idea to have an html file with 57623 rows. if you need to view all these data, either use JavaScript to load dynamically or divide the view into several pages which is easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think your machine is not powerful enough to handle so much data. I can `display` 57623 rows for my data (with 16 columns) without any problem. But my machine has 252GB memory, and it still took about 1 minute to display these data in jupyter notebook.

If I tried to scroll through the data, it's slow, and sometimes stuck for a while.

On the other hand, what do you want to achieve by displaying all data here? There's definitely another way to achieve the same thing as you are doing now.